# Laravel - Additional column in relation many to many

Tags: php, sql, laravel, voyager

I have two tables - doctor and department and the relation between them doctor_has_department.

I would like to add a boolean isBoss column, but I have no idea how I can change the value in it and refer to it in laravel.

I would like to make a checkbox, if it is checked it will change the value to 1.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add an additional relationship to `departments` - such as `department_boss` - which is keyed by the doctor id?

Answer (score 8):

Once you have added the additional column on the pivot table, update the relation to also include this.  Example:

```
public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department')
            ->withPivot('is_boss')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and

```
public function doctors()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Doctor')
                ->withPivot('is_boss')
                ->withTimestamps();
        }
```

You can then query it like this:

```
if $department->pivot->is_boss == 1
```

Answer (score 5):

From your question it seems you have ManyToMany relation between doctor and department and for that assuming you have these tables

```
doctors(id, name ...)
departments(id, name ...)
department_doctor(id, doctor_id, department_id, is_boss ...) pivot table with is_boss pivot field and default laravel naming convention
```

Now Define your relationship in model

**Doctor Model**

```
public function departments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department', 'department_doctor')
                ->withTimestamps(); //if you have different pivot table name then replace department_doctor
}
```

**Department Model**

```
public function doctors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Doctor', 'department_doctor')
                ->withPivot('is_boss')
                ->withTimestamps(); //if you have different pivot table name then replace department_doctor
}
```

**Now insert**

```
//get doctor id and is_boss from request
$doctorId = $request->input('doctor_id');
$isBoss = $request->input('is_boss');

//now save it using relation
$department = Department::find(1);
$department->doctors()->attach($doctorId, array('is_boss' => $isBoss));
```

For details check it https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many